# Asp.net master page duplicate titles

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I understand this has been discussed before several times on SO, but looks like I have a different scenario.

I have a master page with no `<title>` tags at all. All the content pages have their title set up in the @Title page directive.

Recently, a requirement came up such that, only for a single page, which is a content page for the master page, the title should be generated dynamically. I use a user control to get the dynamic content and set the page title.

Now as it is known with the behavior of master pages, the single page with dynamic title has an empty `<title>` tag.

As many other posts on SO suggests, I can set an invisible  tag on the master page to fix this, but then the title for all the other pages which has title set as the page directive, goes missing.

May be having a separate master page for the one single page with dynamic title is a workaround, but are there any other solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For a one single page(MyPage.aspx/MyUserControl.ascx)

***MyPage.aspx/MyUserControl.ascx code behind***

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Page.Title = "Dynamic";
}
```

The same code will work on user control's `page_load` method also, as it is referring `this.Page`

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately, I cannot set the title on page load, it has to come from a user control.

Comment: @itsbalur, put the same code in user control page load. Please see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing. On the Master page, I added a content place holder like below

```
<head>
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="title" runat="server">Default Page Title Here</asp:ContentPlaceHolder></title>
</head>
```

And on the pages with static title, just put the content inside the title placeholder

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="title" runat="server">
    XXX - Static Title
</asp:Content>
```

And on the dynamic title page, called the user control instead of static title like

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="title" runat="server">
    //call user control here
</asp:Content>
```